# Isn't it okay to define relative font-sizes for child elements when the parent element uses Pixels (px)?

Tags: css

**1)** I came across **[THIS ARTICLE](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/)** today, which states:

> The most popular method in working with em values is to set the
>   font-size on the body to 62.5%. Because the default browser font-size
>   is 16px, this makes it 10px (without hard-setting it to 10px, which
>   wouldn't cascade).

What I just quoted (above) essentially means that, I CAN'T set the font-size of the body to 10px directly and then define the font-sizes of other elements in em or % based on that. Isn't it what it meant, or did it get it wrong?

For example, I have `body {font-size: 10px;}`. And now I set `p {font-size: 1.4em;}`. Doesn't it mean, the font-size of `p` is actually 14px? Isn't that cascading? (or is this going to cause me problems on other devices? - - mobiles, tablets, etc.)

---

**2)** For any given element, defining its `font-size` as 1.8em or 180% makes no difference what-so-ever, right? I mean precisely, for an element (whose size we are defining), an `em` is essentially a decimalized form of `%`, isn't it?

---

**EDIT: 3)** 'em' is often referred to as a very mobile-friendly sizing unit. How about %? Is it just as good, considering Q2?

Comment: Well, it may be "The most popular method", but that doesn't mean you CAN'T do what's not as popular.

Comment: Well, did you try? Did it work?

Comment: @BoltClock I don't care if it's popular. The method makes a lot of sense actually, it makes stuff easier. But I want more control, and use 10px directly instead. I hate any "gotchas!" in the process, and that the reason why I am asking it here.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas : I did and it worked. But I was wondering if there are any "gotchas!" that I'd be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The article is wrong when it says that font size in pixels “wouldn’t cascade” (and this reflects a misunderstanding of what the cascade is). You can use `em` or `%` for the font sizes of inner elements if you like. You would be setting font size in pixels for them, just indirectly. The flexibility you get is that things will be easier if you later change the base font size set in pixels. On the other hand, `em` or `%` settings may imply rounding that will be treated differently by different browsers in some cases.

If you set `body {font-size: 10px;} p {font-size: 1.4em;}`, then (unless other style sheets interfere), the `font-size` of `p` will be 14px. But this has nothing to do with the cascade. It’s a consequence of basic definitions for units and `font-size`.

2) For `font-size`, `1.8em` and `180%` have the same meaning by definitions. There used to be reasons to favor one or the other, due to browser bugs with the other, but these considerations have lost significance.

3) Yes, using `%` is just as good.

Comment: Just one last question. Point (2) from your answer - *`There used to be reasons to favor one or the other, due to browser bugs with the other, but these considerations have lost significance.`* Is it safe to say IE7+ don't have these bugs?

Comment: @Kr1s, yes, I would not expect to see such bugs in browsers still in use these days.